# cannot read push of undefined in angular 6

Tags: angular

here is my typescript component code

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
     messages = [];
     @ViewChild('message') message: ElementRef

     socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

     constructor(private route: Router) {


         this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
     }

     ngOnInit() {

         this.socket.on('initial', function(message) {
             console.log(message);
             this.messages.push(message);
         })


     }
 }
```

this.messages.push() gives the error that push cannot be called on undefined

Comment: `this` inside the callback is not the component instance.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost here. One thing you missed is to keep context `this`:

So try using arrow function as below:

```
this.socket.on('initial',function(message){
                               ||
                               \/
this.socket.on('initial', (message) => {
```

Comment: Thanks it worked can you tell me how removing function keyword make a difference it will help me increase my knowledge on this

Comment: For more details please refer this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this